# Can't figure out where data of the vector is lost

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm not so sure how to formulate my question so I'll try to be as concise as possible and ask for patience from you all.

Main:

```
MovieStore ctr{ repo };
MovieStoreGUI gui{ ctr };
```

MovieStore class ( ctr ):

```
class MovieStore {
    Repo& repo;
public:
    MovieStore(RepoAbstract& rep) noexcept :rep{ rep }{}
    const vector<Movie>& getAll() const
    {
        return rep.getAll();
    }
```

Repository class:

```
class Repo{
protected:
    vector<Movie> all;
public:
    vector<Movie> getAll(){return all;}
```

And here is the class where I want to implement the guy:

```
class MovieStoreGUI{
private:
    MovieStore& ctr;
    void reloadList(vector<Movie>);
public:
    MovieStoreGUI(MovieStore& ctr) : ctr{ ctr } {
        reloadList(ctr.getAll()); // here is the problem
    }
};
```

My problem: I can't send the vector that contains the Movies in the reloadList function, no matter what I do, it arrives as an empty vector in the function ( { size = 0 } in debugger ). I also tried `ctr.getAll().size()` in main and it shows the correct value , but here it's a different story.

I don't know if I shared enough info on this bug, so please ask for more context if it is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with

```
const vector<Movie>& getAll() const
{
    return rep.getAll();
}
```

Here you are returning a reference to `rep.getAll()`, but `rep.getAll()` is a temporary object.  That means when the return statement ends that the returned vector is destroyed and you are left with a reference to a vector that no longer exists.

To fix this you either need to make `Repo::getAll()` return a reference, or make `MovieStore::getAll()` return by value.

Comment: could you show me how should i set ```MovieStore::getAll()``` return by value?

Comment: @john Get rid of the `&` in the return type.

Comment: thanks alot, i'm noob, i've been trying to figure this out for the past 3 hours

Comment: given the context, I'd think the solution should be adding a & in Repo::getAll()'s return type (make it return by reference) to avoid necessary vector copy.